# GitLab-CI: Why do stageless pipelines show all jobs under stage "test"? Can this be changed?

Tags: gitlab, pipeline, default-value

I've moved my pipeline to a "stageless" one, simply by using `needs` rules and removing all `stage` declarations.

This all works fine, but I've noticed that all my jobs now appear under a single stage called "Test".

This is not a functional problem, but it does make developers question why it's the case. Is there any way to change this default stage name with Cloud-hosted GitLab?

Is it as simple as setting all of the jobs to use `stage` with the same value? Seems like a bit of a hack, and contrary to the instructions to "remove all `stage` keywords from .gitlab-ci.yml".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the documentation on [stages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stages),

> If a job does not specify a stage, the job is assigned the `test` stage.

For your question:

> Is there any way to change this default stage name with Cloud-hosted GitLab?

You can define a single stage by using the following:

```yaml
stages:
  - some-other-name
```

and then referring to the new stage name (`some-other-name`) in each of your jobs, because (from the same reference above)

> if a stage is defined but no jobs use it, the stage is not visible in the pipeline

Comment: Thank you for making the effort to respond, I appreciate the clarification.